# Insert textbox into Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox, webforms

I have a Gridview which has its datasource set to a DataTable. This has been done due to the data required which is not held in a database. Two columns are generated in this fashion. What i need is a third column to have a textbox, so users can enter their comments etc.

My code is

```
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
    Dim row As DataRow

    ' Generate Columns
    dt.Columns.Add("Col One")
    dt.Columns.Add("Col Two")
    dt.Columns.Add("Textbox Col")

    ' Populate rows with required data
    row = dt.NewRow
    row.Item("Col One") = SomeData
    row.Item("Col Two") = SecondaryData
    row.Item("Textbox Col") = InsertTextbox("data")

    ' Add row to DataTable
    dt.Rows.Add(row)

    gvData.DataSource = dt
    gvData.DataBind()
```

The above code does exactly what i require except when Inserting the textbox (InsertTextbox). The textbox code is

```
Private Function InsertTextbox(ByVal TBText As String) As TextBox
    Dim tbox As TextBox = New TextBox

    With tbox
        .Width = 100
        .Height = 25
        .Text = TextboxText
        .ID = TextboxText
    End With

    gvData.Controls.Add(txtbox)

    Return txtbox
End Function
```

The above code has been changed a few times to see how i could have allowed textboxes to be inserted into a gridview cell.

Currently i get the data back as required but the Textbox Col shows as System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox. Adding .Text shows the text (in this case data) but its displayed in a label format meaning you cant enter anything inside it.

Could anyone advise how i could insert a textbox in this fashion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a `Templatefield` in the gridview and place a `PlaceHolder` control inside the `Templatefield`.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" >
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField>
         <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder_InputControl" runat="server" />
         </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
```

Use the `RowCreated event` to add the textbox dynamically:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCreated(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim pc1 As PlaceHolder = DirectCast(e.Row.Cells(0).Controls(1), PlaceHolder)
        Dim tb As TextBox = New TextBox
        With tb
                .Width = 100
                .Height = 25
                .Text = TextboxText
                .ID = TextboxText
        End With
        pc1.Controls.Add(tb)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. This has finally added the textbox as required :) but the problem i have now is that the textbox is placed under the first column and not the third...... I THINK i may have to create the itemTemplate in code which ill have a look at. Would this be correct or am i missing something? Once again thanks